# When to use equal and unequal variances

Tags: statistical-significance

I have 17 patients who underwent cervical plating, I have calculated

1. preoperative cervical measurements like angles at certain level to be operated, total cervical angles
2. same parameters calculated after operation
3. same parameters calculated after 2 years of operation

Now, which test should I use, and in case it is a paired t-test whether to use equal variance or unequal variance? What happens to degrees of freedom in each case?

Comment: The choice of tests is directly connected to your research questions. Could you please formulate them as precisely as possible? Btw. there is no such thing as a paired t test with unequal variance.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the site.

Since you have 3 measurements for each person, you  don't want a t-test. Probably what you want is a multilevel model with time as the independent variable (probably treated purely categorically) and the measurements as dependent variables. These are fairly complex statistical tools. You probably want one model for each type of measurement, unless you are also interested in the changes in the relationships among the dependent variables, in which case things get very complex.

Not to presume, but if you are wondering about t-tests then you  might want to consider hiring a statistical consultant for this type of modeling.

Do you also have a control sample?