# T-test. Whether to assume equal or unequal variance

Tags: excel

Is it acceptable to assume unequal variance for my data to perform a t-test. If so, what is a justification for this?

Comment: Many simi Qs. Must be a dup: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/313471/always-use-welch-t-test-unequal-variances-t-test-instead-of-student-t-or-mann, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/413313/clarification-on-equal-variance-vs-unequal-variance-t-test, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/422616/two-sample-t-test-with-unequal-variances, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72042/when-to-use-equal-and-unequal-variances,

Comment: You can do a test to check for this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F-test_of_equality_of_variances